# Where is the historical center of Tlalpan?

Tags: mexico, landmarks, mexico-city

[Tlalpan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mexico_City/Tlalpan) is a huge district of Mexico City, but Wikivoyage says:

> The Centro Historico of Tlalpan comprises an area of maybe 6 x 6 blocks, which can be done by foot.
>   You can stroll through the streets around the Plaza de la Constitucion

Despite trying all kinds of searches in Google Maps, I am unable to find that place.

What are the **latitude/longitude of the Plaza de la Constitucion**, in Centro Historico of Tlalpan?

[image: Tlalpan City Hall]

The Centro Historico of Tlalpan also has a large [Spanish Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centro_hist%C3%B3rico_de_Tlalpan), unfortunately without latitude/longitude information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tlalpan#Tlalpan_center):

> The center of this former village is the main square or garden
>   officially called the “Plaza de la Constitución” but better known as
>   the “Jardín Principal” (Main Garden).

You can then look it up in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Centro+de+Tlalpan/@19.2870527,-99.1675378,18z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sJard%C3%ADn+Principal,+tlalpan!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x7be48460535e3627) to get its latitude and longitude, specifically **19.289 W, 99.167 N**.

The surrounding buildings match those in Wikipedia, e.g. La Jalisciense, the San Agustin Church and Casa Frissac.

Comment: I had spotted that square in my research but somehow with Street View it did not look like a touristic area s I dismissed it too quickly... thanks!